# Understanding how Javascript resolving variables globally

Tags: javascript

If I open a javascript console on a web page and add a variable:

```
var abc = "Hello";
```

Javascript attaches that property to the `window` object so I can simply access the object by `window.abc` or directly `abc`

```
console.log(window.abc)
console.log(abc)
```

Now, if I try to access something not defined yet through the `window` object

```
console.log(window.notdefinedyet)
> undefined
```

It simply returns undefined. So if I do

```
console.log(notdefinedyet)
```

why is that an error and not just `undefined`?

Comment: Because `abc` is [`hoisted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) to the global scope and `notdefinedyet` is not.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee that's not what hoisting is. Hoisting doesn't affect the scope but how the binding is created. Hoisted bindings will be addressable *before* reaching the line that "officially" declares them due to hoisting. It doesn't make something a property of the global object or not.

Comment: @VLAZ `abc` is hoisted to the global scope which in this case is the Window object

Comment: @KunalMukherjee - As VLAZ said, that's not what hoisting is.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee *that's not what hoisting does*! Read the very link you provided - hoisting will *effectively* make the code `console.log(a); var a = 1` execute as if `var a; console.log(a); a = 1` - *that* is what hoisting does, doesn't attach anything anywhere

Comment: This is a good question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because trying to read the value of an *undeclared identifier* is a ReferenceError. This is fundamentally a different operation from trying to read a property from an object that the object doesn't have.

Trying to use an undeclared identifier is usually a bug (for instance, a typo). That's part of why ES5's strict mode made assigning to an undeclared identifier a ReferenceError (instead of the old behavior — still in loose mode for backward-compatibility — where it creates a new global variable, something I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)).

One could argue (and many have) that trying to get a property from an object that the object doesn't have is also a bug. But it's often really useful to get `undefined` instead of an error in that case. Whether one agrees with that distiction, this is how JavaScript is defined.

---

It's probably worth noting tangentially that this business of global variable declarations creating properties on the global object is legacy behavior that has to remain in place for backward compatibility, but isn't consistent with current thought on language design in TC39 (the committee behind JavaScript standards). Newer constructs like `let`, `const`, and `class` don't create properties on the global object even when used at global scope (although they do create globals):

```js
var a = 1;
let b = 2;
console.log("a" in window); // true
console.log("b" in window); // false
console.log(a);             // 1
console.log(b);             // 2
```

Comment: Let me get this clear. So in browser `Window` is the global object. My current context is `Window`. That is why if i do, `console.log(this)`, it returns `Window` global object. Same way, if I access global variable (existing or non-existent), It directly looking for it in `Window` and `Window`'s scope chain, right?

Comment: But, If the runtime could not find a property in `Window` or it's scope chain, runtime may return `undefined` or throw `ReferenceError`. If user access non-existent property of `Window` directly that's an error `console.log(notdefined)`. However, if user access non-existent property of `Window` through the object itself, it returns `undefined`, because it's useful?

Comment: @CoderS - Identifier resolution is done like this: The JavaScript engine looks for the identifier in the *lexical environment object* for the current execution context. If the identifier isn't defined in that env object, the JavaScript engine looks at the containing env object (if any) or throws a ReferenceError (if it runs out of nested env objects without finding the identifier). At global scope, the env object is the global object, which is the window object on browsers. But object property lookup is fundamentally different: When you look up a property on an object, the JavaScript engine...

Comment: ...looks at the object to see if it has the property and, if it does, looks at the object's prototype to see if *it* has the property, and so on until it runs out of prototypes. If it never finds the property, the result of the lookup is the value `undefined`. The mechanisms are just completely different, and designed for different use cases. Identifier resolution throws a ReferenceError if you try to use an identifier that isn't defined anywhere. Property lookup doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It always check for reference so console.log(notdefinedyet) gives an error but in case of console.log(window.notdefinedyet), window has reference of object type built in only thing it does not have notdefinedyet key